# How to capture html in an input field

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to send data to my controller based either off a URL or a Embed video file and I can't seem to send a video to my controller.

Example:

A user enters this `iframe` in the input field.

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>

<input id="urlVideo" type="text" />
```

Now if the user enters a website, say `www.google.com`, it passes through, but sending html doesn't work. How am I able to capture this as a string to pass?

I tried JSON.stringify($('#urlVideo').val()); but that didn't work.

```
var url = $('#urlVideo').val();
$.ajax({
     url: '/Main/Controller',
     data: url,
     type: 'POST',
 }).done(function(results){
    // code
  });
```

Comment: Do you want to insert the iframe html inside the text input and then you want to retrieve that html?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "send data to my controller" (what controller?) or "it passes through" (to what?) or "sending html doesn't work" (What HTML? Is the user typing an HTML document into a text input field?)  The question would be a lot easier to follow if you included code demonstrating what you're trying to do, and were explicit about what type of input is failing (and how so.)

Comment: I updated it, so im taking the value of the input field and sending it back to my controller as a string to save

Comment: And what isn't working as expected?

Comment: It is breaking at the AJAX, it is not going to the controller if the user inputs an embeded iframe video. If its just a link, example www.link.com it works fine, so i have to believe its because there are characters in the input that it doesn't like, which I tried to stringify

Comment: One last try, here: What do you mean "it is not going to the controller"?  The POST is happening, clearly; is the browser throwing an error message on certain types of input? (and if so, what input specifically? Are your users literally typing in an iframe tag?) Is the server throwing an error? Are there no errors but something in your `.done()` handler isn't working correctly?  If there are errors, what is the error message you're seeing?   Please be more specific in your questions; "it didn't work" is not a problem statement we can help with.

Comment: ok the error is I'm getting a status 500, Internal Server Error, the done handler works correctly EXCEPT when the user has a value that uses HTML

Comment: OK then.  That means this is a problem in your server-side code, not the client side, so it's going to depend on whatever `/Main/Controller` is doing with whatever input is causing the problem. Check your server logs to see if there's a more specific description of what went wrong; try running that controller against the same input directly to see where it fails, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing HTML over AJAX call to C# MVC Controller. 500 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32910940/passing-html-over-ajax-call-to-c-sharp-mvc-controller-500-error)

Answer (score 0):

OK for future reference, I was able to find out the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32910940/passing-html-over-ajax-call-to-c-sharp-mvc-controller-500-error) using [ValidateInput(false)] over my controller.